# Rails: How to change the logger filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'd like to change the logger filename. The default, say, on production, is `production.log`.

I'd like it be customized, for example, to `production.mymachine.log`.

How can I do this? I can't find any obvious way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this application wide in `config/application.rb` or for each environment in their dedicated files in `config/environments`

```
# e.g. in config/environments/development.rb
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', 'development.my_machine.log'))
```