# Difference between Logger and ActiveSupport::Logger in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Rails (specifically, Rails 6) defines ActiveSupport::Logger, which seems to be a wrapper of (one of Ruby's standard libraries) [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new) according to the [docs and source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Logger.html).

However, in the [current official Rails reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) as of October 2020 for Rails 6.0, the standard Logger is used in a config file. (It used to be ActiveSupport::Logger, maybe?)

Now, I would like to specify a different filename of the logfile from the default (`log/development.log` in the development environment) in the config file (e.g., `config/environments/development.rb`). Does

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/my_log_file.log')
```

suffice?  Or, is it better to use ActiveSupport::Logger?  If so, what is the difference?

Note that in the default `config/environments/development.rb` no setting to follow or modify is defined about the logfile name. Still, `log/development.log` is created automatically in the development environment, so it must be defined somewhere obscure.

[EDIT] [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737408/rails-how-to-change-the-logger-filename) suggests the way I put. I confirm it seems to work in my environment. But there is no reasoning why so… ActiveSupport::Logger is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: How to change the logger filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737408/rails-how-to-change-the-logger-filename)

Comment: @Eyeslandic Thank you for your comment. Yes, but partially. The suggested way is what I have been trying in Rails 6 if rather blindly and so far it seems to be working. I would like to understand why. Is ActiveSupport::Logger just an internal-use class working behind the scene, and Rails-6 app developers do not have to care? If so, that would answer my question. In older versions of Rails, I saw people using ActiveSupport::Logger, I think.

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Logger` adds some conveniences on top of `Logger`. For example, temporary silencing of the logger or broadcasting to multiple loggers. If you don't need these features, I think the standard `Logger` should work just fine and without the overhead.

Comment: @RocketR I see, so `ActiveSupport::Logger` is indeed a wrapper. Would you write it as an answer, perhaps with relevant references, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you explained in your question, `ActiveSupport::Logger` is indeed a wrapper for the standard `Logger` (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb), and a quite thin one.

The main differences are that

- `AS::Logger` configures a default log formatter and
- provides a [`silence`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb#L17-L19) method to temporarily raise the log level and thus "silence" the logging below that level for the duration of a block. It also seems to contain a harness for chaining multiple loggers (the `broadcast` class method).

Rails uses `AS::Logger` unless anything else is specified in the config. They currently mention the class in the docs:

> Rails makes use of the ActiveSupport::Logger class to write log information.

Later they go on to use the standard `Logger` in a code example. Probably, just for illustrative purposes.

To use one or another depends on whether you need the default formatter and the silencing. If you don't, `Logger` will work just fine and also save a tiny bit of overhead. Or you can prefer `AS::Logger`, because it's more universal.